# Shorten copied text with javascript to protect blog from copying articles

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have added this code to functions.php of my wordpress blog:

```
function add_copyright_text() {
    if (is_single()) { ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function addLink() {
    if (
window.getSelection().containsNode(
document.getElementsByClassName('post')[0], true)) {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var oldselection = selection;
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read full forex article here: <?php the_title(); ?> <a href='<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>'><?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?></a>"; //Change this if you like
    var copy_text = selection + pagelink;
    var new_div = document.createElement('div');
    new_div.style.left='-99999px';
    new_div.style.position='absolute';


    body_element.appendChild(new_div );
    new_div.innerHTML = copy_text ;
    selection.selectAllChildren(new_div );
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(new_div );
    },0);
}
}


document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>

<?php
}
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_copyright_text');
```

It works just fine, but I want to shorten copied code.

I replace this line

```
var oldselection = selection;
```

to

```
var oldselection = selection.toString().substr(0,500);
```

But it still copies full length articles.
Can you please help me to modify the code in order to shorten text as well?

BR

Answer (score 1):

You're shortening the `old_selection`, which is not used the way you think it is.

You need to shorten `selection`, but do it *after* it's been copied to `old_selection`, like so:

```
selection = window.getSelection();
var oldselection = selection;
selection = selection.toString().substr(0,500);
```

Later, `selection` is used to populate the new div, which is why you need to shorten *that* variable, not `old_selection`.

Comment: No, not working, giving the error :( http://prntscr.com/9qmmim

I guess it's because it's string now.

Comment: In order to help, I need to know what 'the error' is exactly.  Please provide any / all errors that are being generated.